# Should I go for masters in graphic design or continue self taught?

Tags: education

Ever since I finished my bachelors in American culture and literature I have been begdrudgingly working as an english teacher for the past 6 years. I have always enjoyed drawing and have done countles tutorials, read books etc to improve myself.

I find myself wanting to break away from teaching at this point in my life. I am confident that If I allot all my time to illustration and digital art in general I will be able to break into the gaming industry.

Comparing myself to other peoples work and seeing my own improvement I can give myself a 6 out of 10 overall. My question is, I finally quit my teaching job and have this large sum of money saved up. There is this university where I live that offers a masters in graphic design.

If I go for it, that means dumping ALL my saved money on it. I looked at the curriculum and the people over there told me I could take extra lessons that they teach during the bachelors to catch up. Should I go for it? Do you guys think the skills theyll teach and people I will meet warrants dumping all my money and be supported by my family for the next two years or should I just stay home, draw crazy everyday and get subscribed to some online schools that specializes in game art and digital art.

Comment: No one can really answer this for you. It's all very dependent upon your skill set, creativity, ability to learn, and financial responsibilities. All of which no one here will have the slightest clue about. For what it's worth.. I don't think I've ever met anyone with a Masters in Design, unless they were teaching design.

Comment: This is quite the debated topic on here. There is a wealth of content on the subject: this is a good one: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/768/is-design-school-a-requirement-for-graphic-design/772#772

Comment: I dont really have any financial responsibilities, I would just like that money being there for my peace of mind. As for the other stuff you have mentioned I am confident in all those areas. Never had any formal training and even with a full time job I had the determination and discipline to imrpove myself. A narrower question then, in your opinion would the lessons being taught there actually have any relevance to what I would like to achieve ?. I saw in the curriculum that they are teaching illustration and advanced illustration, which I never took. Thank you.

Comment: I will have a look, Its my first time here, thank you Jenna.

Comment: Being "confident" is one thing, being *capable* is another. You may be both. I wouldn't know. I'm not suggesting you pursue the Masters or that you don't. But you should look at statistics related to degrees vs employment. [(Graphic Design Statistics)](https://www.bls.gov/ooh/arts-and-design/graphic-designers.htm) The truth of the matter is gaining employment with or without a Masters will most likely present the same level of difficulty. The market is saturated and agism for *creative* positions is a very real thing in the industry, although no one will admit that to you for legal reasons.

Comment: My comments are **not** meant to deter you. Really.. I love what I do and value the education I received. One of the best decisions of my life. But if you are slightly older than high school graduates, you should be aware that the longer you wait, the less appealing you may be to employers, and ultimately a strong portfolio outweighs *any* education for most positions. Unless your desire is a more production-oriented position.

Comment: And of course, having a strong portfolio *and* the education customarily makes you a no-brainer hire for many employers, provided money can be agreed upon and you're not.. uhm... too.. uhm.. weird :)

Comment: You would start as a nobody anyway, unless you already know how good you are. You give yourself a 6/10. What does that mean? Have you ever published your work in some competition or contest?

Answer (score 3):

Why not prepare some kind of portfolio and try to get a job in gaming based on what you've already learnt. That way you keep your savings and you have a chance to learn more in the field that interests you directly. If gaming is what you want to do, then direct experience with a gaming company will be more relevant than a masters, which could ultimately send you into another direction.

Another thing you can consider is paying for a course (online or offline) in illustration that will teach you the extra skills. This can be quicker and cheaper than doing the actual masters, which can include a lot of things you may not be interested in directly.

Comment: Good point. The reason I dont want to do that yet is I dont feel quite ready for it. My work in general is not there I feel like. I read somewhere that that could be very dangerous as you can be know as 'that guy with the average stuff' around the circles. Maybe Its a parannoid thought I dont know.

Comment: I don't know. Get an entry level job so nobody expects you to do any magic at first. You'll probably be helping other more experienced colleagues with their work. But still a great way to improve your skills and learn what interests you.

Answer (score 1):

First, to give substantial advice I would need to know a lot more. You know the course, yourself, and your goals better than I do, so you should ultimately just do what you think best. Also, look into the quality, reputation, and "reviews" from students of the University's design school, and decide if its a high enough level that its worth your time and money.

But,
If I were you I would do online courses. While I find that its easier to learn in person, online classes can still help a lot, and are much cheaper. I think at the current stage in your life (although I'm much younger so what do I know) its better to save your money, and maybe try to pick up small jobs for start-up companies to help make a little money and gain experience as you go. I agree with Lucian about creating a Portfolio, that's very helpful, and you'll only get hired if you've got work collected that would make others interested in you.
Best of luck!

Comment: Hi David, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat]. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!